# Auth0 Rule Not Working w/ API Call from React Native App

Tags: react-native, auth0

I’ve been using `Auth0` in my `React` web app. I also have a rule that works with new user sign ups. In my web (`React`) app, I use the `Lock` library and everything works fine.

Now, I created a `React Native` mobile app and because I have a custom login/sign up UI, I had to use the API method as opposed to using an `Auth0` library such as `Lock`, etc.

My SignUp API calls work fine and create new users but my rule is NOT working with API calls. I checked to see if rules apply only to my web app but I don’t see any setting for that so I assume all rules should work for all apps that appear on my dashboard – including my new `React Native` mobile app.

The rule I created on `Auth0` creates and assigns a new `my_app_id` to the new user. This rule has worked flawlessly with all sign ups coming from my web app which uses the `Lock` library but it doesn't seem to be firing when a new sign up comes in through the sign up API end point.

Is there anything I need to do so that my rule will work with my API calls?

Comment: Rules run on successful authentication. Are you using the signup endpoint only?

Comment: I use both authentication and sign up end points in my `ReactNative` app but the rule is designed for new sign ups. I'm calling the sign up end point with a `POST` call at `https://mydomain.auth0.com/dbconnections/signup`. My `POST` call includes the required properties i.e. `client_id`, `connection`, `email` and `password`. As I mentioned in the original post, the sign up actually works. When I log into my dashboard on `Auth0`, I do see the new user but as I said the rule doesn't work. I clarified what my rule does in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules only run after a successful *authentication event*. This would **not** include a successful signup endpoint call, where no credentials are authenticated.

The recommended way to hook to a signup would be through a [registration hook](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks).

Comment: Thank you! I also got a response on Auth0 community forums. Looks like my current approach is working because I'm using the `Lock` library which first registers a new user then logs in the user. Because of the second step i.e. login, my rule works. Again, thank you for your help!